# Print the prediction of convolutional neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, data-science-model, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

I have designed a convolutional neural network using tensorflow which looks as follows

```
#Define a convolutional neural network function
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

    conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4, k=2)


    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Output, class prediction 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out
```

The code I'm using to train and test the model is as follows :

```
#Train and Test the Model
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    train_accuracy = []
    test_accuracy = []
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Output', sess.graph)
    for i in range(training_iters):
        for batch in range(len(X_train)//batch_size):
            batch_x = X_train[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(X_train))]
            batch_y = y_train[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(y_train))] 
            # Run optimization op and Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                 y: batch_y})
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
        print("Iter " + str(i) + ", Loss= " + \
                      "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        print("Optimization Completed")

        # Calculate accuracy for all test data
        test_acc,valid_loss = sess.run([accuracy,cost], feed_dict={x: X_test,y : y_test})
        train_loss.append(loss)
        test_loss.append(valid_loss)
        train_accuracy.append(acc)
        test_accuracy.append(test_acc)
        print("Testing Accuracy:","{:.5f}".format(test_acc))
        summary_writer.close()
```

This prints the accuracy but not the predictions. How can I print the predictions?

p.s new to neural network

Answer (score 1):

You can replace these lines:

```
opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                     y: batch_y})
loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                  y: batch_y})
```

by:

```
opt_, loss_, acc_, out_ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accuracy, out], feed_dict={x:batch_x,
                                                  y: batch_y})
```

In this way, you can evaluate all the parameters given in the list (optimizer, cost, accuracy, out) in a single *sess.run()*. After, if it is classification task, you will probably need to apply *softmax* and *argmin* to *out*_